Shutdown Apache Spark batch job programatically
My use case is to start a spark job from Dolphin Scheduler or Airflow. This job will read the data from the Apache Pulsar stream for a timespan, process the records, and then shut down or close the application completely.
The above will repeat for a cron pattern, and I do not want the job to be running full time as it will consume the resources and I want to executors to shut down, however, the master can continue to run.
I tried implementing the below and it is not working. I am also wondering if there is a way by which Spark does it on its own.
public class CardTransactionStreamProcessor extends StreamingQueryListener {

    public static final String PULSAR_SERVICE_URL = "pulsar://127.0.0.1:6650";
    public static final String TOPIC = "spark/tutorial/card-txn";
    public static final String SUB = "my-sub";
    public SparkSession sparkSession;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException, StreamingQueryException, InterruptedException, AnalysisException {

        CardTransactionStreamProcessor streamProcessor = new CardTransactionStreamProcessor();

        streamProcessor.sparkSession = SparkAppUtil.getSparkSession("card-txn-stream");
streamProcessor.sparkSession.conf().set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", true);

        Dataset<Row> lines = streamProcessor.sparkSession.readStream()
                .format("pulsar")
                .option("service.url", PULSAR_SERVICE_URL)
                .option("topic", TOPIC)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("pulsar.reader.readerName", "my-sub-card-txn")
                .load();

        lines.printSchema();

        Dataset<CardTransactionDTO> cardTransactionDTODataset = lines.as(ExpressionEncoder.javaBean(CardTransactionDTO.class));

        cardTransactionDTODataset.printSchema();

        cardTransactionDTODataset
                .writeStream()
                .trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow())
                .outputMode("update")
                .format("console")
                .start();
        streamProcessor.sparkSession.streams().addListener(streamProcessor);
        streamProcessor.sparkSession.streams().awaitAnyTermination();
    }

    @Override
    public void onQueryStarted(QueryStartedEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Query started%n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onQueryProgress(QueryProgressEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Query in progress%n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onQueryTerminated(QueryTerminatedEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Query terminated%n");
        sparkSession.stop();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

